# Bug. Creating Account does not have text box labels

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, status-declined

I am using IE8, tried to "sign-up" with StackExchange (as opposed to the Google or Facebook choices).  I was presented with 4 blanks that were un-labeled.  I had to guess what they were for (the error handling worked great here!!)  I figured out that the 2nd was for email and the 3rd was for password and the 4th was for password validation.  I got lucky and it did "sign me up".  I received an email to validate my account.  One other thing I wanted to point out.  After I responded to the email and then used the back key (I was trying to get to the page that caused me to get to stackoverflow in the first place)....then the signup was displayed -- still with no text box labels BUT this time it did have a captcha (which when I signed up it did NOT have and I did NOT have to use the captcha).
Seems like a bug.

Comment: Screenshot and cleaning up your question would help, but generally speaking, IE8 is not supported by Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 9):

We are using placeholder attributes for the signup/login form elements (as well as the comment box) - IE8 doesn't support those and we will not be fixing it.

The behaviuor of the captcha is by design. That is, what you have noted is how it is supposed to work (to avoid bots trying to signup multiple times).

Comment: My company currently only allows IE8 (whatever!).